# Opening Reveal model on page load not working

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am working on Jquery Modal where it is easily opening on href click
 and shows the pop up window.
 My **html Page** is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Reveal Demo</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="reveal.css">   

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.reveal.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            body { font-family: "HelveticaNeue","Helvetica-Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif; }
            .big-link { display:block; margin-top: 100px; text-align: center; font-size: 70px; color: #06f; }
        </style>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('a[data-reveal-id]').live( 'click',function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var modalLocation = $(this).attr('data-reveal-id');
                        $('#'+modalLocation).reveal($(this).data());
                });
            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">
            Fade and Pop
        </a>    

        <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
            <h1>Reveal Modal Goodness</h1>
            <p>This is a default modal in all its glory, but any of the styles here can easily be changed in the CSS.</p>
            <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

> My **Output** is

[image]

As you see this pop window is opening on click of "Fade and Pop" link.

but i want to open this pop window on page load. I tried very much but
i dont get result. Where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are calling the reveal in `a` click event , calling it inside the `document.ready` should work..

try it in document.ready function

```
$(document).ready(function() {  //or  $(window).load(function(){ 
    $('#myModal').reveal($(this).data());
});
```

Comment: I tried this but it is not working. Have you gone through same problem?

Comment: no but this should work... are you getting any errors ? check your console

Comment: welcome... glad it helped... cheers... happy coding friend.. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to ensure both things on click of the link popup should happen and on page load too. so what you can do is just add `.click()` at the end of closing as below and see if this works for you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('a[data-reveal-id]').live( 'click',function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var modalLocation = $(this).attr('data-reveal-id');
       $('#'+modalLocation).reveal($(this).data());
   }).click();
});//-^^^^^^^----------------add this
```

Comment: the above code works but you need to change .live with .on and remove .click() from the end ( for latest version of jquery )